# Joda Time: how to parse time and set default date as today's date

Tags: scala, date, time, jodatime

I have to parse dates in formats:

```
HH:mm 
dd MMM 
dd MMM yyyy
```

I've managed to handle the last two of them:

```
val dateParsers = Array(
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM").getParser,
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").getParser,
    ISODateTimeFormat.timeParser().getParser
)

val formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, dateParsers).toFormatter.withZoneUTC
DateTime.parse(updatedString, formatter.withDefaultYear(currentYear).withLocale(ruLocale))
```

Everything is ok with `dd MMM` and `dd MMM yyyy`, but when I'm trying parse time like `05:40` I'm getting `01-01-1970` date instead of today's date. What is the simplest method to set default date as today's date in parser?

Comment: You could try and add the current date with time 00:00:00.000 to the parsed time. There seems to be a class `DateMidnight` so you might want to add your parsed time to an instance of that class.

Comment: Is this Java? Looks like another JVM language.

Comment: Another option might be `DateTime.withTimeAtStartOfDay().plus( yourParsedDateTime.getMillis())`. Note that you might have to handle timezone differences or specify time zones but I'll leave that for you.

Comment: It is scala actually, I fixed tags

Comment: @Thomas The "midnight"-related classes and methods are deprecated. (a) Midnight is difficult to define. (b) The first moment of the day is not necessarily the time `00:00:00.000` because of Daylight Saving Time nonsense and possibly other anomalies. Instead use the new [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method. `DateTime today = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joda-Time-Formatter only supports `withDefaultYear()`, not things like `withDefaultDate()`. Instead you can do this:

```
DateTimeFormatter timeParser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime time = timeParser.parseLocalTime("05:40");
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault(); // Or DateTimeZone.UTC or DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" )
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(tz);
DateTime moment = today.toLocalDateTime(time).toDateTime(tz);
System.out.println(moment);
// output in my local timezone: 2014-08-20T05:40:00.000+02:00
```

Note: I have written the solution in Java, because I am not a scala-guy.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` and `Time` are completely different, without subclassing `DateTimeFormatter` and implementing your special "time at todays' date"-algorithm you wont get very far. Either subclass or maybe inject your current date into the string if it matches some regular expression

Comment: I did use injecting, but I hope there is more suitable method for this. I think subclassing is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use withDate()

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
@Test
public void test() {
    DateTime dateTime = FORMATTER.parseDateTime("05:40");
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    dateTime = dateTime.withDate(now.getYear(), now.getMonthOfYear(), now.getDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(dateTime.toDate());
}
```